# when I import firebase using import * as firebase from 'firebase';?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

shows me this error?

Unable to resolve "firebase" from "App.js"
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

I have tried looking for answers but these were for previous verisons for firebase I also tried adding this import too but didn't solved my problem.

import firebase from '@firebase/app'

```
},
 "dependencies": {
"expo": "^33.0.0",
"firebase": "^6.3.0",
"native-base": "^2.12.1",
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk- 
33.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.3.0",
"react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
"react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
 },
```

can someone help

Comment: You may want to check out this article that explains about using firebase with Expo https://blog.expo.io/using-firebase-in-expo-e13844061832

Answer (score 17):

You should update the imports & code this way to make it work out.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = { // Have the firebase config here
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

// Use this to initialize the firebase App
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

// Use these for db & auth
const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { auth, db };
```

Comment: Spent 2 damn hours searching to eventually find out that I missed the ```/app';``` in  the first import statement. Thank you! Btw: can you explain why we need the "compat" addition?

Comment: Yeah I've spent sometime to come to a conclusion as well.
The compat is for version 9 of firebase to be compatible with version 8.

I guess they're going to change it from compat to modular for the next version.


Reference link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat

Answer (score 5):

If You are using Version 9 then don’t forget that things changed a bit for importing firebase Now there is a “compatibility” option so can use the /compat folder in your imports. Here is an example.

```
//to use firebase app
import firebase from 'firebase/app'; //older version
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'; //v9

//to use auth
import 'firebase/auth'; //older version
import 'firebase/compat/auth'; //v9

//to use firestore
import 'firebase/firestore'; //Older Version
import 'firebase/compat/firestore'; //v9
```

Answer (score 3):

In the docs of `firebase` npm package they say:

> If you are using native ES6 module with --experimental-modules flag, you should do:
>
> ```
> // This import loads the firebase namespace.
> import firebase from 'firebase/app';
>
> // These imports load individual services into the firebase namespace.
> import 'firebase/auth';
> import 'firebase/database';
> ```

So try **replacing**

`import * as firebase from 'firebase'`

with

`import firebase from 'firebase/app'`

You may also consider using firebase wrapper build for react-native https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase. It will require from you an extra setup described in the docs, but works better.

Comment: I downgraded my firebase from 6.0.3 to 5.0.3 and error disappeared but when I  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((authenticate)=>{
        if(authenticate){
            this.props.navigation.replace("homeScreen")    
        }else{
            this.props.navigation.replace("signInScreen") 
        }
    }) it shows Can't find variable :firebas

Comment: With firebase functions, where can you specify the node --experimental-modules flag?  I understand how to use the flag if running node from a command-line, but how can you specify it if you're using the firebase "serve" command?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript? In TS these modules work by default I think, maybe with a change in tsconfig. I haven't used firebase in JS (not TS) on Node.js actually...

Answer (score 1):

Try:

npm install --save firebase

Answer (score 0):

Import like that

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/storage";
```

// Your web app's Firebase configuration

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
};
```

// Initialize Firebase

```
const app = !firebase.apps.length
  ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : firebase.app();

const db = app.firestore;
const auth = app.auth;
const storage = firebase.storage;

export { auth, db, storage };
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, that if you are using a newer version of firebase, i.e > 9.x, then use this instead:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
```